# Useful applications of \edef with macro arguments

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

Well, it's been in my head for some time, but I haven't got anything out of it, so I ask here. At what places could be useful to have `\edef\foo#1{..}`? What applications could it have? Is it useful at all?

Here's one example. `\foo` gives ten thousand times the argument after one expansion. Of course, this probably could be done in another way, but seems like a good example.

```
\def\byten#1{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}
\edef\foo#1{\byten{\byten{\byten{\byten{#1}}}}}

Ten thousand letters: \foo{a\hskip0ptplus1pt}
\bye
```

But apart from that, I've been looking for a chance to use `\edef\foo#1` and it hasn't appeared.

To make this answerable, in case some applications don't appear, or there's no interest in the question, it could also be answered like *Have you ever seen `\edef` used that way?* or for instance *Is there any use of this in a full TeX Live installation?*

### Note

The question is not clear enough, the suggestions of egreg and Heiko are both acceptable answers, since they are uses of `\edef` with arguments. However, what I was looking for are situations where the argument are inside the argument of a macro that gets expanded when `\edef`ed (like in my example). I don't know how to write this clear, feel free to edit the question.

Comment: There are some examples in `etoolbox.sty`

Comment: Those are indeed examples, `\edef`s with arguments. But not what I was looking for; I mean, those examples are just “basic” just stop expansion for a few things and expand just one bit (e.g., a `\detokenize`). I was looking more about uses where `#1` is expanded inside a macro inside the `\edef`.

Comment: That always happens with `\write`. Note that in your example you don't expand `#1`: only macros get expanded in `\edef`. Doing `\edef\foo#1{\byten{#1}}` is the same as doing `\def\foo{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}`

Comment: That's what I (tried to) mean, I know `#1` is not expanded, but is “moved around” by the expanded macros. If you, or anyone, can clear the question, feel free to edit. I don't understand what you mean about `\write`, though.

Answer (score 15):

Searching for `\edef` or `\xdef` (global variant) with command to be defined and argument in TeX Live 2015 and filtering out possible false positives (when the command is constructed with `\csname`):

```
 egrep -r '\\[ex]def\\[a-zA-Z@]+#1' texmf-dist/tex/ | grep -v '\\[ex]def\\csname'
```

Result are 219 lines.

I do not want to discuss all findings, thus I restrict myself to few examples.

### Example `\TextOrMath` of the LaTeX kernel (`latex.ltx`)

Recently, macro `\TextOrMath` was added to the LaTeX kernel:

```
\edef\TextOrMath#1#2{%
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname TextOrMath\space\endcsname
  {#1}{#2}}
```

Here, the `\edef` has the purpose to construct a macro name with a space in it: `\TextOrMath␣`. The definition would simpler, if the space would be a letter:

```
\def\TextOrMath#1#2{\TextOrMath␣{#1}{#2}}
```

But, this is not possible with the usual category code of the space. An alternative with `\def` and lots of `\expandafter` is more cumbersome:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\TextOrMath
\expandafter#\expandafter1\expandafter#\expandafter2\expandafter{%
  \csname TextOrMath\space\endcsname{#1}{#2}%
}
```

Therefore, `\edef` works on the non-argument part of the definition text. To make it clear, arguments are *not* expanded during the definition with `\edef`, `#1` to `#9` are non-expandable tokens.

### Example `\split@err` of package `amsmath`

Another example can be found in package `amsmath`:

```
\edef\split@err#1{%
    \@nx\@amsmath@err{%
        \string\begin{split} won't work here%
    }{%
        \@xp\@nx\csname
  Did you forget a preceding \string\begin{equation}?^^J%
  If not, perhaps the `aligned' environment is what
  you want.\endcsname}%
}
```

Here, the argument is not used at all, it is ignored as part of the error recovery.

### Example `\mleftright@Def` of package `mleftright`

Package `mleftright` has an example, where the argument is used three times:

```
\edef\mleftright@Def#1{%
  \noexpand\ltx@IfUndefined{%
    \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\ltx@gobble\noexpand\string#1%
  }{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\mleftright@Def#1%
  }{%
    \noexpand\@PackageError{mleftright}{%
      Command \noexpand\string#1 already defined%
    }\noexpand\@ehd
    \noexpand\ltx@gobble
  }%
}
```

The purpose of the expansion is `\mleftright@Def` inside the definition. Previously, it was defined as `\protected\def`, `\DeclareRobustCommand*` or `\def`, depending, which method is available (e-TeX, LaTeX, or neither of them).

### Arguments `#1`, ...

At definition time, the argument place holders (`#1`, `#2`, ..., `#9`) are just two non-expandable tokens, the hash character `#` and the digit `1` to `9`. Therefore, there isn't a difference between `\edef` or `\def`, because `\edef` cannot expand non-expandable tokens.

The argument place holders get replaced with the actual arguments, when the macro is *used*, that is *after* the definition of the macro.

Comment: This falls into the same category as egreg noted (like `etoolbox.sty`), where the `#1` isn't “moved” by the `\edef`, just other things are expanded. Of course `#n` aren't expanded, there's nothing for them to expand :) I will wait a little bit to see if there's a case where the arguments are *moved* when macros are expanded, and, if it doesn't appear, I guess I will accept this.

Comment: @Manuel I do not know, what you mean with "moved", but I have added two further examples, which do different things with arguments: The argument in the first added example is not used at all and in the other example the argument is used three times.

Comment: I don't know how to state it clearly, I mean that the `#1` is inside the argument of a macro that gets expanded when `\edef`ed.

Comment: @Manual As I said in the answer, `#1` consists of two non-expandable tokens `#` and `1`. `\edef` does not see anything different. The `#1` gets replaced, when the macro is *used*.

Comment: I know. I mean, what I was looking for was any use of `\edef` where the argument of a macro consists of `#1` and the macro does something with that symbolic `#1`. See for instance my example `\edef\foo#1{\byten{#1}}` converts it to `#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1`. Your example is more like `\def\baz{\relax}\edef\foo#1{\baz{#1}}` where `{#1}` is untouched by the expansion of macros inside `\edef`.

Comment: @Manuel `\@gobbletwo` could be defined using `\@gobble`: `\long\edef\@gobbletwo#1#2{\@gobble{#1}\@gobble{#2}}`

Comment: That's a good one. Of course, it's not practical, but yeah, that's a good example. Any other one that is actually used or that you know of? (By the way, if only you and me are talking in the comments you don't need “@Manuel”, I get pinged anyways.)

Answer (score 4):

After a completely false understanding of the question, I have rewritten my answer to show how `\edef` with an argument can be used to "fix" the selected equation citation style.

An `\edef` is evaluated at time of definition, whereas `\def` is evaluated at time of execution.  If `\edef\eqcite#1{}` is used in preference to `\def\eqcite#1{}`, then changes to the supporting formatting macro have no effect, because the `\edef` locks in the definition.  In contrast, when using `\def`, changes to the supporting formatting macro will affect the subsequent equation citations.

Thus, philosophically, the use of `\edef` should be employed when one wants something not to change even if the supporting macros are changed.  The below MWE tries to capture the choice at hand: the use of `\def` allows `\setrefstyle` to change the `\eqcite` behavior on the fly, whereas the `\edef` prevents `\setrefstyle` from having any subsequent effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svref\ref
\def\setrefstyle#1{\ifcase#1\relax
  \def\refstyle##1{Eq.\,(##1)} \or
  \def\refstyle##1{Eqn.\,(##1)} \or
  \def\refstyle##1{equation~##1} \else\fi
}
\setrefstyle{0}% 

% HERE IS THE CHOICE:
\newcommand\fixeqcite[1][T]{%
  \if T#1%
    \edef\eqcite##1{\refstyle{\noexpand\ref{##1}}}% <--- TO NOT ALLOW CHANGES
  \else%
    \def\eqcite##1{\refstyle{\ref{##1}}}%<--- TO ALLOW CHANGES
  \fi%
}
\fixeqcite
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:A}
y=mx+b
\end{equation}
\def\mytest{\smallskip\par
\setrefstyle{0}In \eqcite{eq:A} we see one form of cite\par
\setrefstyle{1}In \eqcite{eq:A} do we see another form of cite?\par
\setrefstyle{2}In \eqcite{eq:A} do we see a third form of cite?\bigskip\par}

Eqcite definition (with edef) is of fixed format, by default.\mytest
But I can let it be redefined (with def) on the fly.\fixeqcite[F]\mytest
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But here you are using `\edef\foo{..}`, so `\foo` has no arguments. This is the normal use of `\edef`.

Comment: @Manuel Apparently, I misunderstood the question.  I'll delete and rethink.

Comment: @Manuel I have totally revised my answer.

Comment: Well, this is one of those things I was looking for. Not magical, but gets to the point. I'm looking for cases where the benefit could be clear. And if no  case of those appear, then I'm looking for packages that already use this “trick” on TeX Live, for instance.

Comment: @Manuel I have revised my answer to better lay out the `\edef`/`\def` distinction and how it may be used to achieve a desired behavior.

Answer (score 3):

There is a usage of `\edef` with parameter in special expansion control. One nice (yet quite complicated) example can be found in `skeyval-core.tex` v1.3 on line 1997

```
\skvrobustdef*\skvpopfunctions#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\skv@elt{\skvnoexpandcs{\skvremovescape{#1}@skv@stack}}%
  \expandafter\skvifdefTF\skv@elt{%
    \expandafter\ifx\skv@elt\@empty
      \skv@err{Stack of '\noexpand#1' is empty}\skv@ehd
    \fi
  }{%
    \skv@err{Stack of '\noexpand#1' is undefined}\skv@ehd
  }%
  \edef\skv@prova{\skvexpandtwice\skv@elt}%
  \edef\skv@provb##1##{\endgroup##1\gdef\skvexpandonce\skv@elt}%
  \expandafter\skv@provb\skv@prova
  \skvgadvanceno#2\m@ne
}
```

I'm not sure I understand the details, but certainly `\skv@provb` is defined by `\edef`, standard `\def` wouldn't work here (since `\skcexpandonce` is used inside) and it takes an argument.

This is a significantly more complicated case of what Heiko shows; here you could probably get around having `\edef\....##1` in the code if you wished, but the effort to do so would have to be really big.

Comment: This is not an example of what I'm looking for. Here `##1` is not “touched” inside of the `\edef`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one of the uses I was looking for (it's practically the same code I used in the question, but at least it's public and useful code :D)

The [l3benchmark](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3trial/l3benchmark/l3benchmark.dtx) package, at lines 420–421 has a nice definition of `\@@_replicate_kibi_fold:n` (`@@` is symbolic):

```
\cs_new:Npx \@@_replicate_kibi_fold:n #1
  { \prg_replicate:nn {1024} {#1} }
```

> As its name indicates, expanding this function once yields
>   1024 copies of its argument. This is used to avoid reaching the
>   limits of TeX's memory in case the user input is a very simple
>   piece of code.