# How to force edef to execute def

Tags: macros, expansion

Since I haven't given up on my problem from yesterday, I've been messing around with `\edef`, `\def`, `\unexpanded`, `\expandafter` and some other stuff. I also read about fragile commands and robust commands. As far as I can see, a robust command gives the same result anywhere in the document, contrary to fragile commands, which depend on context (therefore `\chapter` must be fragile).

Now I read, that `\edef` doesn't execute `\def`s. But how can I expand and force the execution of a `\def`.

example:

```
\def\any{content}
\def\changeAny#1{\def\any{#1}}
\def\textA{text}
\edef{\changeAny{otherContent} \textA}
```

This will break because edef will expand to

```
\edef\foo{\def\any{otherContent} text}
```

will expand to

```
\edef\foo{\def content{otherContent} text}
```

this causes `\inaccessible`-error after `\def`

---

Additional info:

I also experimented with flag replacement:

```
%existing fragile
\def\fragileCommand{original Content\\ of fragile}

\def\flag{\unexpanded{\flag}}
\let\fragileCommand\flag
\edef\texty{blabla \fragileCommand blabla}
\def\fragileCommand{original Content\\ of fragile}

\texty
```

That prevented from breaking, but didn't give (always) the desired result.

Comment: `\def\flag{\unexpanded{\flag}` leads to a recursion, I think

Comment: This feels like an 'X-Y' problem: what is the actual problem to solve?

Comment: `\chapter` is fragile due to the moving argument(s)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It does, if I don't redefine it later.

Comment: @JosephWright How to force the execution of a def inside a edef.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: So what's the point of posting it here? ;-)

Comment: @MaestroGlanz 'You can't' : `\edef` performs expansion not execution. In the same way, `\expandafter\foo\def...` doesn't do anything (as `\def` is not expandable).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Simple: Maybe there is a way to force the execution. I don't know, I'm no TeX-master yet.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well the code comes out to `\def\fragileCommand{\unexpanded{\flag}}` so it's OK

Comment: @MaestroGlanz As Joseph said: what's the actual problem to solve? What is it that led you to want to execute `\def` inside `\edef`?

Comment: @JosephWright Is there an alternative. Or a possibility to do a workaround?

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes, I saw that, but code above fails in a recursive loop (using `pdftex`, not `pdflatex` or course) and adding a `\bye`)

Comment: I suppose there is no general answer to this problem. If so, this also helps me to find a solution (it refers to yesterday's problem).

Comment: @MaestroGlanz We still don't know what do you want to achieve. This is like asking if we can transform gravity to repel objects: no, we can't, but why on earth would you want that? Please, add that info to the question, and we will be able to help you. And “yesterday's problem” is not a nice reference: post a link in case it's relevant and add the details to the question itself.

Comment: The StackExchange model doesn't work by date (questions get reordered) so a cross-ref is needed here to help with your other question.

Comment: This is the same as yesterday's question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311241/environment-behaves-different-inside-cslet you post code without saying what you want to do. The title question here is impossible to answer since edef stands for expanded def it _always_ does a def

Comment: It is not that there is "no general answer to the problem" it is "it's impossible to guess what the question means"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do say, what I want to do. The answer to at least this question is simply: It is impossible. - A thing I didn't knew before respectively wasn't sure about. This is the same problem as yesterday, but it isn't the same question. Yesterday I didn't understand, why the code broke, now I understand a bit more.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz I mean it is the same problem with your question style, that leaves it not answerable You post code without saying at a higher level the intention, so all anyone can do is say syntactically what is wrong with the code, not suggest alternatives. you can not say it is impossible to force an edef to make a def as it always does that `\edef\foo{hello}` is identical to `\def\foo{hello}` in behaviour.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: I think, one problem to understand what you want to achieve is that it's out of context. There might be other ways to solve your problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The example I just made, is a typical code break example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know, but I can do alternatives on my own, that is not the problem. One suggested idea from yesterday has also been my primary alternative. I know, that it is a bit annoying, but the avoidance of alternative was a basic constraint yesterday. But I know pretty much more WHY it doesn't work and this helps a lot. I appreciate that.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz `\edef{\changeAny{otherContent} \textA}` is wrong, I think  that's a mistake and you wanted `\edef\foo{\changeAny{otherContent} \textA}`. In that case... may be the answer to your whole question is: use `\noexpand` or `\unexpanded`? `\edef\foo{\noexpand\changeAny{otherContent} \textA}` or `\edef\foo{\unexpanded{\changeAny{otherContent}} \textA}` will compile fine!

Comment: @Manuel Right. Exactly. No, this isn't the answer, because this would lead into undefined-errors. The solution to my question is simply: Not possible in exact the way I want to do it.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz What would lead into undefined errors? `\edef\foo{\noexpand\changeAny{otherContent} \textA}`?

Comment: This question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262027/useful-applications-of-edef-with-macro-arguments, is related to the use of `\edef` with arguments, but touches on interactions of `\def`s within `\edef`s.

Comment: @Manuel `\changeAny`is (not in the example, but in the final use) locally defined (constraint) and the argument changes several times in the whole document. What I originally intended to do, can only be solved with aux-files (I would 90% know how to do that, so no problem).

Comment: @MaestroGlanz in that case just expand changeAny once to insert its definition rather than its name into the command being defined.

Comment: Why don't you show us your favourite alternative and explain what you don't like about using that solution? Then somebody might be able to come up with a constructive suggestion rather than playing guessing games. As you may have noticed, we aren't that good at guessing games. At least, we don't seem to be very good at this particular instance.